# Using <include> nested in <merge> tag - Android

Tags: android

I have two reusable layouts, header_item.xml and custom_view.xml (using **merge** tag).
The **custom_view** is always used inside a **LinearLayout** tag.

I want to **include** the header_item inside this custom_view but the Android Studio gives me this error message: "**Cannot resolve class include**".

The strange thing is that I can run the app and it seems to work fine. But I am not sure if it is an Android Studio issue or I shouldn't be using **include** inside a **merge** tag.

Here are the xml files:

header_item:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:text="Header"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:gravity="center"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

and the custom_view:

```
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:parentTag="android.widget.LinearLayout">

    <include layout="@layout/header_item" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="text from custom view" />

</merge>
```

Answer (score 7):

`<include>` inside of `<merge>` works absolutely fine, however Android Studio cannot handle this situation and will show `Cannot resolve class include` error on the  tag. Maybe it will be fixed in the future.

Comment: Still not fixed..

Comment: Android Studio fails to compiled then. So basically alias are not working as defined here: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources#layout

Comment: @Slion <merge /> must be the root element. Internal <include> may show an error, but works fine. Maybe you should try to rebuild your project.

Comment: Yes I think my issue was that it does not work with bindings. So you can't `<layout>` as root.

Comment: Does anybody know if there is a bug-ticket for this I can star? Can't find one, if there is none we should really open one

Answer (score 2):

merge is not a view, [see here](https://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/reusing-layouts#Merge).

so, change the custom_view like following:

```
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        tools:parentTag="android.widget.LinearLayout">

        <include layout="@layout/header_item" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="text from custom view" />

    </LinearLayout>

</merge>
```

Comment: The custom_view is used inside a LinearLayout. The main idea is to avoid this extra LinearLayout.

Comment: @LeonardoSimas Facing the same issue. Did you find any answers/solutions to this?

Comment: @SaketKumar it's just an Android Studio's bug, you can include views inside of merge without any issues (except Studio's warning)

Comment: In case it won't build. That's not just a warning…